# Calculating lost monthly income

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

```
Hotel {hotelID, hotelName, city}
Room {hotelID, roomNo, price, type}
Booking {hotelID, roomNo, startDate, endDate}
```

I want to find the lost income for the current month (i.e. count lost income per each day in the current month and then compute the total)

How do i go about in doing this?

QUICK EDIT: only need to look up income for hotelName = 'Radisson'

Comment: Does "lost income" mean "the amount of money you could have gained if all the rooms which were booked had been booked instead"? What have you tried?

Comment: If you gave some example data/result it would be a whole lot easier to help..

Comment: What have you tried? Also as previously commented, post some test data. You can use [SQL Fiddle online tool](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) to provide all this information. All directly post here a create script with the sample data.

Comment: please explain more about *..lost income for the current month*.

Comment: @user17 What's your lost income/day logic you intend to use?

Comment: Eggplant --> lost income means the amount of money I've lost due to unoccupied rooms and all i have currently is finding the lost income for today:                                                            SELECT SUM(r.price)
FROM Room r
WHERE r.hotelID IN (SELECT h.hotelID FROM Hotel h WHERE h.hotelName = 'Radisson') AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Booking b WHERE b.hotelID = r.hotelID AND b.roomNo = r.roomNo AND
   (b.startDate <= DATE(NOW())  AND b.endDate >= DATE(NOW())));

Comment: *QUICK EDIT: only need to look up income for hotelName = 'Radisson'* what are the other names? Anyway, please provide us some sample/expected data. So people here can try out and match it for you.

Comment: Hint: we won't write the code for you. Hint2: provide code... Hint3: in case of SQL issues, use [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), and set it up properly

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/267ed

Answer (score 2):

Should work:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(r.price), 0) 
    FROM Room AS r INNER JOIN Booking AS b ON r.hotelID = b.hotelID AND r.roomNo = b.roomNo 
    INNER JOIN Hotel AS h ON r.hotelID = h.hotelID 
    WHERE (month(b.startDate) > month(current_date()) OR month(b.endDate) < month(current_date()))
    AND h.hotelName = 'Radisson';
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the start of your query.  you were too lazy to put up data, so i'm too lazy to go lookup mysql form of query...

after looking at per room data - you can consolidate into a single sum if you like.  this is how you write queries to make sure you are getting each step correct

```
select
  ht.hotelid
  ,ht.hotelname
  ,ht.city
  ,rm.roomno
  ,rm.price
  ,rm.type
  ,30 as days -- use your datediff function for month instead of literal 30
  ,30 * rm.price as potential -- use your datediff function instead of literal 30
  ,sum(datediff(day, startdate, enddate)) * rm.price as earned
  --, potential - earned as lost (use the 2 prior columns to calc)      
from hotel ht
join room rm on ht.hotelid = rm.hotelid
left join booking bk on bk.hotelid = rm.hotelid 
   and bk.roomno =bk.roomno
```